# Is this syntax highlighting intended behavior or a bug?

Tags: support, formatting

I came across an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/195990/18612) earlier today which had code blocks containing some text portions in blue. Below is a screenshot of the beginning of the answer for convenience:

[image: Screenshot of blue text]

I have never seen this before, and I saw nothing out of the ordinary when I checked the answer's source. Is this supposed to happen? What triggered it?

Answer (score 5):

As noted by [Anwar's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195983/how-to-copy-files-via-terminal/195990#comment243797_195990) on the answer, this behavior occurs when the [bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bash) tag is used in the question, and adds the coloration to code snippets used in the answers. This is a feature.

- The feature is described here: [Editing helps - Syntax highlighting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)
- Also take a look at this question: [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)

Comment: So cool, huh? :)

Comment: Included the link

Comment: Thanks for the addition, @Anwar ! I had no idea that formatting page existed. This is extremely useful.

Comment: Yeah, you can also request that a tag get syntax highlighting.